# How to upload a file to Parse.com using simple HTML form?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, parse-platform, multipartform-data, enctype

I want to upload a simple image file along with text value to a `Parse.com` project at [www.willubmy.com/create](http://www.willubmy.com/create). But either I am not getting the correct `enctype` or Parse's node requires some changes. Can you please help resolve this issue? I am getting the POST variables normally but am not able to get anything when I send a file along

Simplified HTML

```
<form>
Question:<br>
<input type="text" name="questionString">
<br>
username:<br>
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="file" name="file">
</form>
```

My Cloud Code

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var questionString = req.body.questionString;
    var positiveAnswer = req.body.positiveAnswer;
    var negativeAnswer = req.body.negativeAnswer;
    var email = req.body.email;

    console.log(username + questionString + positiveAnswer + negativeAnswer + email + JSON.stringify(req.body));

console.log("req files : " + req.files);
```

Comment: I assume you're using `body-parser` for your POST data, this doesn't support files. You need to use something like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Comment: Thanks, but `parse.com` doesn't support  `multer`

Answer (score 0):

This documentation can help you:
https://www.parse.com/questions/uploading-files-to-parse-using-javascript-and-the-rest-api

Comment: I don't want to use `API Keys` and the related jazz. I just want to upload a normal file.